# Configure nginx.conf for Rails Shows File Directory Not Index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, nginx, passenger

Here is what I have in my nginx.conf:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;
#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;
#pid        logs/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
     }
http {
    passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.11;
    passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;
    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_types    text/plain text/html text/css
                  application/x-javascript text/xml
                  application/xml application/xml+rss
                  text/javascript;
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  domain.com www.domain.com;

        # autoindex on;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env production;

        access_log  logs/mrfs.access.log;

        location / {
            root   /opt/nginx/html/mrfs/public; #line updated per suggestion below
        }

        }
  }
```

I can toggle the autoindex on and off and it will display a 403 error when it is commented out or a directory listing when it is on. When I have access to the directory listings, I can surf them and download various files. This seems to me to make it not a permissions issue. When I have auto index disabled I get a can not list directory error in the error log. I think what I need to do is tell nginx how to load my index.html.erb file? How do I do that? Is that what is wrong?

***Update***

I put an 'index.html' in my /opt/nginx/html/mrfs/public folder and it loads that. So what would cause rails/nginx/passenger to load index.html file in public, but not load the home.html.erb file in my routes? I can run 'rails s' and then do a wget http://localhost and it pulls down the right html file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I had to change it to:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  domain.com www.domain.com;
        rails_env production;
        passenger_use_global_queue on;
        access_log  logs/mrfs.access.log;
         root   /opt/nginx/html/mrfs/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
       error_page  404              /404.html;
       error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    }

}
```

If you have a `location /` in your `nginx.conf` then you have to put passenger_enabled on; inside of that or else delete the `location /` block. I chose to delete it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the `root` to the `public` directory of your project:

```
server {
    ...
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env production;
    root   /opt/nginx/html/mrfs/public;
}
```

Comment: Does public have a special meaning? I realize it is probably conventional to do it that way and I'll add a public directory and put it all there there. But what I did is just a git pull off my rails repo on github.

Comment: Your rails app should have a directory that is called `public`, it's generated by `rails new`. It's basically the web root of all rails apps.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking something like public_html.

Comment: I added that to my config and it still does the same thing: `autoindex on;` results in directory listing of of the public folder and if I turn it off I get the 403 forbidden error.

Comment: Just to clarify, this was on heroku, but I'm trying to move away from heroku.

Comment: Ok - that repo looks fine. I can't think of any other reason for the behaviour you describe right now.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the 'public' folder correction in the other answer, it sounds to me like there's an issue with permissions/ownership of the folders containing your app.  There should be a line in the nginx.conf like...

```
user websrv;
```

which defines the user that nginx runs itself under. The folder with your rails app should be owned by that user, and permissions should be set appropriately.

Comment: I've added the user lines from my config in to original question above. The default is 'nobody' but root is the owner. I can access the files just fine with `autoindex on` set. Is there a way I could do that if the permissions were set wrong?

Comment: Ok, so what I understand you're saying is that nginx is running as a user named 'nobody', which is good, but that the folders are owned by root, which is not good.  Correct me if I misunderstood. Otherwise, correct the ownership. I have no idea what autoindex would or would not do under those conditions.

Comment: I changed ownership on the whole /html directory to 'nobody' and confirmed this by running `ls -l` on the html directory, the mrfs directory and the public folder. I restarted the nginx server and still get the 403 forbidden error.

Comment: Hmmmm... Ok, so 'nobody' owns all the folders and files within /opt/nginx/html now. Permissions should be rwxrwxr-x on all folders and rw-rw-r on all files.  I don't think that having the app installed in /opt/nginx/html should be a problem, but *maybe* nginx considers that reserved for static html files??? We put our Rails apps in /var/rails/[appname]. Another suggestion is to setup Capistrano to do deploys. Once configured `cap deploy:setup` will prepare all the correct folders on the server and make sure they have the right permissions and ownership.

Comment: I have the apps installed in /opt/nginx/html/[appname]. I just changed all permissions to 777 for everything in the html directory. No change. I have another folder that is just index.html and .css file and it has worked throughout this whole process.

Comment: Well, than I'm at a loss.  This thread might help [link](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/172018)  Good luck!

Comment: I don't know if this makes any difference but I copied an index.html into my /opt/nginx/html/mrfs/public directory and that loads. I really don't think it's a permissions issue. I think it has to do with how nginx or maybe passenger renders the index.