# passenger with nginx on ubuntu linux - not recognizing my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I install passenger on rvm with gem

```
gem install passenger
```

and then install nginx with it

```
rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module
```

and edited the /opt/nginx/nginx.conf file adding this two line to the server issue:

```
passenger_enabled on; 
root /home/snir/my_app/public;
```

but running passenger (after stopping the nginx system service) give me this output:

```
Environment: development
Accessible via: http://0.0.0.0:3000/

You can stop Phusion Passenger Standalone by pressing Ctrl-C.
===============================================================================
2013/04/16 17:47:08 [error] 4730#0: *4 "/home/snir/public/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.1", host: "0.0.0.0"
```

and browsing to 0.0.0.0:3000 gives me a 404 not found page of nginx.
what is wrong? why does passenger look for app at /home/snir/public instead of the route I gave it in the nginx.conf file which is /home/snir/my_app/public?

edit:

so it seems like nginx was not connected to passenger as it wasn't appear at --add-module of nginx. but I installed it correctly, so it might be some other installation of nginx coming with ubuntu that conflict the passenger installation.

Comment: The examples in the guide all set the root before 'passenger_enabled on.' I don't know if it makes a difference, but try it.

Comment: I tried, it's not that..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about your system but the problem might be your using the wrong config file. Most unix bases systems nginx config file is located in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/some-site which is a soft link to /etc/nginx/sites-available/some-site. If your in doubt you can try putting an obvious error in the file you think is the config file your system is using and restart nginx to see if it complains of an error or continues without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I recently worked on setting up servers to deploy to my VPS at DigitalOcean.com and found their support articles to be very helpful. Here is one that might help with your specific situation. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-rails-and-nginx-with-passenger-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

maybe your nginx.conf isnt correct (the location in my case is /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf)

i found a solution that works for me -> [Configure nginx.conf for Rails Shows File Directory Not Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423391/configure-nginx-conf-for-rails-shows-file-directory-not-index)